# Height of UIScrollView in UITableview shorter than table height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a pretty standard `UITableView` with only 1 section. My problem is that the length of the `UIScrollView` (That the `UITableView` inherits) seems to be shorter than the table itself. My table loads and presents the data as it should, seen here:

[image]

Yet, when I scroll to the bottom, the scroll bar on the right is displaying an incorrect height for the scroll view. The scroll bar stops scrolling about halfway down the `UITableView`, where it starts to contract. It is reaching the bottom of the data, but there is unnecessary whitespace at the bottom of the table that I would like to get rid of, as seen here:

[image]

The table is pretty standard, for I am using the Subtitle Style table view cell. Therefore, I am not implementing `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. I am using a custom font, but even when I take it out I get the same results. So I am unsure why this is happening?

This class is very simple. The only methods I am implementing are:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

**EDIT** I now realize that after I make a selection and then select back on the navigation bar, the table displays properly as it should. Something that gets called upon hitting back on the navigation bar fixes it and I have no clue as to what it is!

Comment: Post ur code where ur setting contentoffset for the scroll view.

Comment: @Ganapathy I am not setting contentOffset for the scroll view anywhere.

Comment: So, u simply added UITable view inside the UIScrollview right without setting content offset for scrollview?

Comment: @Ganapathy Well, UIScrollView is a superclass of UITableView. I guess my post is a little misleading. It's the all the same view controller. When I reference UIScrollView, I am referring to the UIScrollView that is used in the UITableView.

Comment: I thought u r customizing the view. ok.

Comment: It sounds like your table view's `contentInset.bottom` is to non-zero.  You should check that in the debugger or with `NSLog`. If that's the problem, you need to figure out why it's getting set wrong.

Comment: @robmayoff Thank you for your response! You were right, `contentInset.bottom` was the issue, although I have no clue how it was being set to a nonzero value! It showed zero in `viewDidLoad`, and nonzero in `viewDidAppear`. After implementing `viewDidAppear` with literally zero lines of code in it, the problem fixed itself... Really strange. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table view has that whitespace at the bottom because its `contentInset.bottom` is greater than zero.

The content inset is non-zero because a `UITableViewController` automatically sets the content inset to the height of the keyboard when the keyboard is showing.  This allows the user to access all of the table view's cells, instead of leaving the bottom cells hidden under the keyboard.  Read about [“Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard” in the *Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7) for details.

Since the keyboard is (I assume) going away when you perform the segue to the table view controller, I  consider this behavior a bug in UIKit.  The workaround is, as you have discovered, to make sure that you tell the first responder to resign before performing the segue to the table view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off autoresizesSubviews for you tableview?

Comment: I just tried it, with no luck. I entered this:    self.resultsTable.autoresizesSubviews = NO;

Comment: Have you tried self.resultsTable.autoresizesSubviews = NO?  (dumb question--its just the only way I know of reproducing this kind of thing... is having this stuff messed up)

Comment: I did, as posted in my response to your initial question.

Comment: Hah, I'm getting tired.. I meant self.resultsTable.autoresizesSubviews = YES (sorry to waste your time and irritate you!)

Comment: No worries! I greatly appreciate your efforts. I switched it to YES and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @robmayoff , the `contentInset.bottom` had a nonzero value, throwing the scroll view of `UITableView` off. I am unsure where this was being changed. I checked the value in both `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`. `viewDidLoad` showed a value of zero, whereas `viewDidAppear` showed a value of nonzero.

All I did to fix the problem is implement `viewDidAppear`. The method is completely blank, and the `contentInset.bottom` is being correctly set. Very strange... but it works.

Comment: It probably has something to do with the keyboard.  Was the keyboard showing when you pushed the table view controller?

Comment: @robmayoff YES! The keyboard was showing upon the time of segue. I just fixed it so I call `[searchBar resignFirstResponder]` and it fixed it! Do you know why that caused it? If you want to answer the question I will mark your answer as correct.